# Have hidden content open automatically depending on inbound HTML link

Tags: javascript

I've inherited [this site](http://kalamazoobicycleclub.org/rides/rides.php) and am looking to fix up some things. It currently uses Hideslide.js to expand the different sections of content (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc...)

The previous admin tried to have links on the homepage that would go to that page and have a given content area open, depending on which external link was clicked. This doesn't seem to work at all.

So put it succinctly, is there a way I can link directly to one of those content areas and have it be open when the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can write it manually using fragment urls and calling hideslides showHideContent function onload.

The urls for deeplinking must now contains the ID of wanted day "hideslide_name box". For tuesday use

```
http://kalamazoobicycleclub.org/rides/rides.php#hideslide_q2
```

include this code on your page

```
<script>
var divId = window.location.hash.substring(1);

if (divId)
    window.onload += showHideContent(null, divId);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to almost but not quite work. I have implemented the javascript fragment at the bottom. When you load "http://kalamazoobicycleclub.org/rides/rides.php#hideslide_q2" it gives me a _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null_    However when I run the function in the console, it works as expected.The value of divId is "hideslide_q2" and using that as the parameter for showHideContent(null, 'hideslide_q2') works fine

Comment: Ok. Could you tell me what is logged if you console.log(divId) directly after "var divId ..."

Comment: Sorry to bump (not sure on etiquette of that), but any other suggestion? Thanks.